# Reading unicode elements into numpy array

Tags: python, unicode, numpy

Consider a text file called "new.txt" containing the following elements:

```
μm
∂r
∆λ
```

In Python 2.7, I can read the file by typing:

```
>>> import codecs
>>> f = codecs.open('new.txt', encoding='utf-8')
>>> lines = [line.strip() for line in f2.readlines()]
>>> lines
[u'\u03bcm', u'\u2202r', u'\u2206\u03bb']
>>> print lines[0]
μm
```

So far so good. I can easily convert this list to a numpy array via:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array(lines)
>>> arr
array([u'\u03bcm', u'\u2202r', u'\u2206\u03bb'], 
      dtype='<U2')
```

The issue is, I can't read this file directly via numpy's loadtxt function:

```
>>> np.loadtxt('new.txt', dtype=np.unicode_)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 805, in loadtxt
    X = np.array(X, dtype)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xce in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What is the correct way to read this file into numpy directly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In memory, unicode strings are represented as [UCS-2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UCS-2) or [UCS-4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UCS-4), depending on how your Python interpreter was compiled.  Your file is encoded in [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), so you need to recode it before you can map it to the NumPy array.  `loadtxt()` can't do the recoding for you -- after all NumPy is mainly targeted at numerical arrays.

Assuming every line has the same number of characters, you could also use the more efficient variant

```
s = codecs.open("new.txt", encoding="utf-8").read()
arr = numpy.frombuffer(s, dtype="<U3")
```

This will include the newline characters in the strings.  To not include them, use

```
arr = numpy.frombuffer(s.replace("\n", ""), dtype="<U2")
```

**Edit**: If the lines of your file have different lengths and you would like to avoid the intermediate list, you can use

```
arr = numpy.fromiter(codecs.open("new.txt", encoding="utf-8"), dtype="<U2")
```

I'm not sure if this will internally create some temporary list, though.

Comment: +1 -- but a note: you can pass an open file directly to `loadtxt`, and for me, opening the file with `codecs.open` and passing it to `loadtxt` solved the problem. Or rather a similar problem, since my `loadtxt` had no problem with a utf-8 file!

Comment: @senderle: Strange -- doesn't work for me.  I'm using NumPy 1.5.1 here -- maybe this matters.

Comment: Does this have anything to do with using numpy Python 3 port?. I still get UnicodeEncodeError in my numpy which is working under Python 2.7.

Comment: what if the lines have different lengths of which I don't know apriori?

Comment: that _is_ strange. It may indeed matter -- I'm using a Mac and so far I have lazily refused to install an up-to-date version of python, so I'm stuck with NumPy 1.2.1. It's also possible that MacOS is doing some useful locale magic, as it tends to.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `loadtxt`, you can either first load the raw byte array and then decode:

```
data = np.loadtxt('foo.txt', dtype='S8')
unicode_data = data.view(np.chararray).decode('utf-8')
```

or specify a converter for decoding:

```
data = np.loadtxt('foo.txt', converters={0: lambda x: unicode(x, 'utf-8')}, dtype='U2')
```

However, using `fromiter` as in Sven's answer is probably going to be more effective than `loadtxt`.