# convert unicode array to numpy

Tags: python, numpy, unicode

I have arrays of unicode strings like this

```
u'[(12520, 12540), (16600, 16620)]'
```

and need to convert these to numpy arrays. A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375343/reading-unicode-elements-into-numpy-array) treats the problem of already having an array with unicode elements, but in my case the brackets are part of the string. Is there a way of directly converting this to a numpy array (of ints) without having to manually remove the brackets?

Comment: `np.array(literal_eval(s))`

Comment: Where did you _get_ these strings from? If you've got some code that printing out or otherwise stringifying a bunch of lists or arrays for you to convert back later, it's almost always better to keep the lists or arrays themselves than to convert them back and forth.

Comment: @abarnert that would for sure be better, but I'm working with published data that happens to come in this format, so no way around it in this case.

Comment: @jacob: Even then, it's important to know the actual language of the published data so you know what it's _intended_ to mean. If it's the output of a Python `repr` call, then `literal_eval` is the exact right way to reverse that. If it's some other language which is usually but not always valid as Python source code, then using `literal_eval` is a bad idea. Sometimes the best you can do is guess, but that should never be your first recourse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use literal_eval

```
from ast import literal_eval
import numpy as np
s=u'[(12520, 12540), (16600, 16620)]'

arr= np.array(literal_eval(s))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) as follows:

```
import ast

my_str = u'[(12520, 12540), (16600, 16620)]'

my_nparray = np.array(ast.literal_eval(my_str))

print(my_nparray)
```

Results in:

```
[[12520 12540]
 [16600 16620]]
```

Comment: equally valid answer, of course! Can only accept one, so accepted the earlier one.