# Read file with header and encoding issue into numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, unicode

I have a file (PSF from Zemax if you want to know) that looks like this:

```
Listing of FFT PSF Data

File : C:\G_Drive\Projects\MSE\Telescope\AAO_designs\MSE_PF_6u_1300-Shan-Nicolas_2.zmx
Title: MSE Prime Focus WFC with CLADC
Date : 2/9/2018
Configuration 1 of 4

FFT PSF
0.5510 µm at 0.5300, 0.0000 (deg).
Data spacing is 0.300 µm.
Data area is 153.600 µm wide.
Surface: Image (Focal surface)
Reference Coordinates: 2.02066E+02, 0.00000E+00
Pupil grid size: 256 by 256
Image grid size: 512 by 512
Center point is: row 257, column 256
Values are normalized to peak = 1.0

  1.7638E-02      1.7079E-02      1.6531E-02      1.5996E-02      1.5475E-02    ...
```

So, it has a header with text and what I imagine are characters that have required some iso-8859-1 encoding.
After the header come 512 lines of 512 floats, which I want to import into a numpy array.

I started with this:

```
data = ascii.read(path_in + files[0], data_start=19, encoding='iso-8859-1')
n = np.array(data)
n.shape
```

but the array has not the right shape:

```
(508,)
```

I also tried:

```
im = np.loadtxt(path_in + files[0], skiprows=19)
```

but got the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 211: invalid start byte
```

And np.loadtxt does not accept a different encoding.

I have then tried things like:

```
arr = np.fromiter(codecs.open(path_in +files[0], encoding='iso-8859-1'), np.float)
```

but this does not like the header:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Listing of FFT PSF Data\r\n'
```

Finally, I found some similar question here: [Reading unicode elements into numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375343/reading-unicode-elements-into-numpy-array), but this:

```
s = codecs.open(path_in + files[0], encoding='iso-8859-1').read()
im = np.loadtxt(s)
```

gets me the "IOPub data rate exceeded" error message, even though I bumped the rate a lot.

Comment: In Numpy 1.14, the `loadtxt` function has an `encoding` parameter. Maybe you can upgrade your SciPy package?

Comment: for some reason I cannot update Numpy beyond 1.13.3 (using conda/anaconda on MacOSX)

Comment: switched to conda/anaconda 64, was then able to update to Numpy 1.14 and use `loadtxt` with `encoding` parameter!
thanks a lot @lenz

Comment: Good to hear it worked. Since your question already got some upvotes, it might be worthwhile to have an answer to it. Why don't you answer your own question, describing how you got it to work? It might become valuable to future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use `loadtxt` with Numpy 1.14, which has the `encoding` parameter.

However, to upgrade to Numpy 1.14 at the time, I had to switch to anaconda-64.